# Why is the number of exotic spheres equivalent to $S^7,S^{11},S^{15},S^{27}$ equal to perfect numbers?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

> https://oeis.org/A001676 Number of exotic spheres
>
> https://oeis.org/A000396 Perfect numbers

$S^7 \to 28$ = 2nd perfect number (28)

$S^{11} \to 992$ = 2 times 3rd perfect number (496)

$S^{15} \to 16256$ = 2 times 4th perfect number (8128)

$S^{27} \to 69524373504$ = 2 times 5th perfect number (33550336)

These are the only cases. It doesn’t seem to exist any other correspondance between those 2 sets.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hm, what's "hom"?

Answer (score 11):

[According to this blog post](https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/the-kervaire-milnor-formula/) (which summarizes the results of Kervaire and Milnor), the number of exotic spheres of dimension $4k-1$ is
$$\# \Theta_{4k-1} = R(k) \cdot \# H_{4k-1} \cdot B_{2k}/2k,$$
where:

- $R(k) = 2^{2k-2} (2^{2k-1} - 1)$ for odd $k$, twice that for even $k$;
- $H_{4k-1} = \pi^{\mathrm{st}}_{4k-1}$ is the $(4k-1)$th [stable homotopy group of spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Table_of_stable_homotopy_groups);
- $B_{2k}$ is the $2k$-th [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Note that the image of the [$J$-homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-homomorphism), a subgroup of $H_{4k-1}$, is cyclic, and its order is precisely the denominator of $B_{2n}/4n$, so the formula always gives an integer. Moreover for small $k$, the numerator of the Bernoulli number is $1$, and the J-homomorphism is surjective or has a small index (e.g. 2) so you really get an equality $\# \Theta_{4k-1} = R(k)$, or up to a factor $2$. For bigger $k$ this doesn't work.

Now it turns out that the 45 first [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) are of the form
$$P_p = 2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$$
where $p$ is prime, $p = 2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61$... This is of course the number $2 R(p)$ above. So this is how the two are related. Note that if $k$ isn't prime then you don't actually get a perfect number. (It is known that all *even* perfect numbers are of this form. Now don't ask me why perfect numbers are even... Because nobody knows!)

The example you found ($S^7$, $S^{11}$, $S^{15}$ and $S^{27}$) are all of the form $4k-1$, with $k = 2,3,4,7$. For these, the formula above gives for example with $k=2$:
$$\# \Theta_7 = R(2) \cdot \# H_7 \cdot B_4 / 4 = 2^{2 \cdot 2 - 1} (2^{2 \cdot 2 - 1} - 1) \cdot 240 \cdot 1/30 \cdot 1/4 = P_2.$$
For the other $k$ you can do similar computations.

Comment: I think you mean $P_p = 2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$. Also, it is known that every even perfect number must be of this form; see the [Euclid-Euler Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese You're right, thanks. (To my knowledge it's not know whether there exist odd perfect numbers though, right?)

Comment: Yeah, that's still open.

Comment: For the last part, $\pi^{s}_{4k-1}$ splits as the direct sum of the image of the $J$-homomorphism and another group. The former has order equal to the denominator of $B_{2k}/4k$, so the right side of the formula for $\#\Theta_{4k-1}$ gives an integer.

Comment: @anomaly Ah yes, of course!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I would like to know if there is a deeper reason rather than a coincidence in formulas. For example, take a look at this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/329902/exotic-spheres-in-physics/329910#329910

Also, there is also a bosonic string theory whose n orthogonal groups is quite close to 8128 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269387910963

Furthermore, the size of its algebra is close to the number of exotic spheres of S27, which is close to the dimension of the number of space time dimensions of the bosonic theory.